# Toggling menu in bootstrap stops <a href=""> from working

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I tried adding a toggle to every link in my menu so the menu would close on mobile after pressing a link. I found a solution for this by adding `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"` to the `<a href=""?>`. Now this solution worked in bootstrap 3 but in bootstrap 4 it still closes the menu, but doesn't link to the text put in the `<a href="">` anymore.

Why does this stop from linking to the link and how do I solve this?

The following fiddle shows the problem, I added a comment above both the links without toggle and the links with toggle. Ignore everything around it, I'm pretty sure it issn't in any of the code around it.

**code:**

```css
.block{
  height: 200px;
  padding: 100px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-top: 3px solid gray;
}

.navbar li a {
  color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto container px-md-5">
            <!-- Links WITHOUT data-toggle -->
            <li data-menuanchor="block1">
                <a href="#block1">block1</a>
            </li>
            <li data-menuanchor="block2">
                <a href="#block2">block2</a>
            </li>
            <li data-menuanchor="block3">
                <a href="#block3">block3</a>
            </li>
            <!-- END of Links WITHOUT data-toggle -->
            <!-- Links WITH data-toggle -->
            <li data-menuanchor="block1">
                <a href="#block1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">block1 (with toggle+target)</a>
            </li>
            <li data-menuanchor="block2">
                <a href="#block2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">block2 (with toggle+target)</a>
            </li>
            <li data-menuanchor="block3">
                <a href="#block3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">block3 (with toggle+target)</a>
            </li>
            <!-- END of Links WITH data-toggle -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
      
<a name="block1"></a>
<div class="block" data-anchor="block1">block1</div>
<a name="block2"></a>
<div class="block" data-anchor="block2">block2</div>
<a name="block3"></a>
<div class="block" data-anchor="block3">block3</div>
      
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I'm also open for other solutions, like solutions in JavaScript or html.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Menu Name 1 </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a href="#block1" class="dropdown-item">Submenu 1-1</a>
                <a href="#block2" class="dropdown-item"> Submenu 1-2</a>
                <a href="#block3" class="dropdown-item">Submenu 1-3</a>
            </div>
        </li> 


       <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Menu Name 2 </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a href="#link1" class="dropdown-item"> Submenu 2-1</a>
                <a href="#link2" class="dropdown-item"> Submenu 2-2</a>
                <a href="#link3" class="dropdown-item"> Submenu 2-3</a>
            </div>
        </li> 
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't need everything to be in a menu inside it, I want the menu to close AND link to a anchorlink whenever I press 1 of the links in the menu.